# Banner Ad is Moved When Scene is Switched due to SKCameraNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, startapp, skcameranode

So, in my project, I have a main menu screen with no SKCameraNode. The banner ads work perfectly fine and nothing happens to them until I click the play button. I am using StartApp ads. Here is my main menu screen:[image: Banner Ads Main Menu]

And when I switch scenes, the SKCameraNode messes with the positioning of the banner ad and moves it. So then, in every other scene I go to the banner ad isn't in the correct position. How can I fix this?

Here is an image of the gameplay scene:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The banner ad is a view and has no relation to what is going on with the scene.  This means you are somehow manipulating the `SKView` that the `SKScene` is attached to in some way to cause the position to change.  Check your code and your storyboard to verify that your views are properly handled, and that you are not changing constraints or any kind of layout properties.